# Were the Salem Witch Trials caused by sociopaths, ergotism, hallucinations, or mass hysteria?

Tags: history, hallucinate-hallucogenic, sociopath

In the spirit of Halloween, I'm thinking of the medical reasons that contributed to the Salem Witch Trials? Was it caused by sociopaths, or classic food poisoning -- ergotism -- or mass hysteria or hallucinations?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  Thanks!